# why mocha assertion fails on mongoose.Schema.objectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am asserting somewhere in mocha as :

```
assert.equal(model.organizationId,objId);
```

But i am getting the failed mocha result as :

```
Uncaught AssertionError: "5225777180a843d901000012" == "5225777180a843d901000012"
```

why it happens, when the id's are same.

And how to overcome it?

Comment: If you're using ShouldJS then you can use `var1.should.equal(var2)` for `===` and `var1.should.eql(var2)` for `==`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So mongodb ObjectIds in javascript are sadly frustrating in this regard. They are distinct objects resulting in `obj1 === obj2` evaluating to false even though the value they represent is identical. There are 3 options:

1. Convert to strings before comparing. I use this a lot because it's so frustrating otherwise.
2. Use the `.equals()` method they provide: `assert.ok(model.organizationId.equals(objId))`
3. Write a custom comparison function that can take null, ObjectIds, or Strings and do the right thing (I've also done this)